# Magento configuration popup window - where should html file go in module hierarchy?

Tags: magento

In my module config, I have a button. When that button is clicked I pop up a window that gathers some more input. That file is just an html file, but where should it live in the directory structure of the module?

To give a bit more info - just to see something working, I defined my field as follows:

```
<button_url_test_window_open><![CDATA[/px.html]]></button_url_test_window_open>
<frontend_model>mymodule/adminhtml_system_config_testWindowOpenDialog</frontend_model>
```

and I put the px.html file in my htdocs/magento folder. When I click the button it results in /px.html being opened, but that doesn't seem right. I'm not sure how to word the question, but I feel I should be doing something more like 'open the file called px.html for mymodule' and magento would then look in the right place. Sorry about the terminology, I'm still getting to grips with Magento/PHP/Apache.

Just to complete the picture of what I currently have, the frontend_model block is:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
        $this->setTemplate('mypackage/system/config/test_window_open_dialog.phtml');
    }
    return $this;
}

public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
    return parent::render($element);
}

protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $originalData = $element->getOriginalData();
    $this->addData(array(
        'button_label_test_window_open' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__($originalData['button_label_test_window_open']),
        'button_url_test_window_open'   => $originalData['button_url_test_window_open'],
        'html_id' => $element->getHtmlId(),
    ));
    return $this->_toHtml();
}
```

and the test_window_open_dialog.phtml file contains:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button style="" onclick="javascript:window.open('<?php echo $this->getButtonUrlTestWindowOpen()?>', 'testing','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, ,left=100, top=100, width=600, height=470'); return false;" class="scalable" type="button" id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>">
                <span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getButtonLabelTestWindowOpen()); ?></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

phtml files don't go anywhere within your module directory.  Module directories house your Blocks, Helpers, Models, Controllers, Sql installation/upgrade files, and your configuration xml files.  Template files go in either app/design/adminhtml (if it is an admin template), or in app/design/frontend if it will be used on the frontend of the site.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Rather than /px.html, should my window.open be taking a parameter of /myfrontname/mycontroller/myaction?